# How to wrap GoogleMap fragment into a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

I tried this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          map:mapType="normal"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

But I got 2 errors:

1. `<fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`:

> Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag fragment

2.`map:mapType="normal"`:

> Unexpected namespace prefix "map" found for tag fragment

What am I doing wrong, and how should it looks like in order to integrate more objects except the Google Map in my app...

thnx !

**EDIT !!**

I tried this, and it works !

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              map:mapType="normal"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can't understand why.. also can't understand what `map:mapType="normal"` and `xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` means... ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

From http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html it looks like the two attributes are not needed.

i also substituted `class` for `android:name`.

To use the `map` attributes you need to add the namespace (i think you can add it to the `LinearLayout`, more information at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#using_xml_attributes .

If the attributes aren't working i'd probably just set the values programmatically.

Comment: I edited my question... please look and try to help me with this.. thx !

Answer (score 1):

For what I know it a known bug that if you wrap your map with a layout, you can't use `map` prefix properties on it and you have to customize the map in your code.

Comment: I did: <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="253dp"
          android:layout_weight="0.96"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       />

and: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        map:mapType="normal"

outside the Fragment, on the LinearLayout's root... is it OK ?